# How to Configure trusted SSL keystore with Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, https, ssl-certificate

Want to introduce HTTPS protocol (trusted certificate) to my Spring Boot(1.3.2.RELEASE) application.
For this purpose tried next SSL properties:

```
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:key.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=pass
```

and have the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:131) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSslKeyStore(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:340) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSsl(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:323) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
```

In that error you can see that **configureSslKeyStore** should be passed.
When I am trying to launch the application with next set of changes:

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:key.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=pass
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:key.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=pass
```

Application starts successfully but https is not reachable:
[image]

So now I have several questions:

- What can be the reason of such behavior, that protocol is unsupported?(Certificate is fresh and not outdated)
- Is it correctly that there is no way to configure trusted certificate without redundant properties?
- Is there some other more convenient way to configure trusted
  SSL?

**UPDATE:**

It is JAR file and certificate exists inside of it classpath:key.jks"".

Comment: Add steps that you took to import the certificate AND the matching private key into the jks.

Comment: And tell us where in the .war file the `key.jks` file is. NB You should not use the same file as both keystore and truststore. They serve completely different purposes.

Comment: Certificate exists inside spring boot JAR file, not WAR.
"matching private key into the jks?" Could you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: "So tell us where in the Spring boot JAR file the key.jks is"
It is in the question: server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:key.jks

Comment: classpath:key.jks. The absolute path is: C:\project\src\main\resources\key.jks. Is it can have some influence to my problem?

Comment: @Speise No. `classpath:key.jks` is where you *specified* where it is, and where it clearly *isn't,* otherise you wouldn't be asking the question. `C:\...` is where it is in your source code. I am asking for the actual location *in the JAR file*, which would consist of a line of a `jar tvf` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was in my .jks file. It was generated in a wrong way.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544253/difference-between-entry-type-keyentry-and-trustedcertentry-in-a-keystore) where you can find the correct structure of storekeys.